# R: Why PieDonut() is not available?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have installed packages like webr,moonBook and ggplot2 and added my dataset. But even after installing packages there is a error:

```
Error in PieDonut(dataset, aes(pies = brand, donuts = year)) : 
  could not find function "PieDonut"
```

Comment: Lacks code and data sufficient to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say with the given information. You probably haven't loaded the packages. You aren't only required to install the packages but you have to load them before you can access their functions. Use the `library`function to load packages.

Comment: I have installed and loaded the package but it's not working.

Comment: Strange. What happens when you try `exists("PieDonut")`? Does `sessionInfo()`confirm that the package is loaded?

Comment: Same problem here: installed, located, and loaded the required packages but failed to run PieDonut and it is not exist

Comment: Sorry, I cannot replicate it. `library(webr); exists("PieDonut")` returns `TRUE` on my system. You may have to [draw the donut chart with ggplot](https://r-charts.com/part-whole/donut-chart-ggplot2/).